# Remove rows based on multiple conditions in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe below:

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|SID     |StartDate |EndDate   |CID     |Date Added|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-26|
|1001    |2021-03-30|2021-03-31|1002    |2021-03-26|
|1001    |2021-04-07|2021-04-09|1002    |2021-03-26|
|1004    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003    |2021-03-26|
|1005    |2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006    |2021-03-26|
|1001    |null      |null      |null    |2021-03-29|
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-29|
|1001    |2021-03-30|2021-03-31|1002    |2021-03-29|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is if there is a null value for the record `SID` in `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `CID`, it will drop the row with null value and other records for `SID` that is less than the `Date Added`. So the result would look like this.

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|SID     |StartDate |EndDate   |CID     |Date Added|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
|1004    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003    |2021-03-26|
|1005    |2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006    |2021-03-26|
|1001    |2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002    |2021-03-29|
|1001    |2021-03-30|2021-03-31|1002    |2021-03-29|
+--------+----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

I know filter can probably help but I'm not really sure how to do it with the other conditions I mentioned. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter those specific rows that have null in `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `CID` then join with the original dataframe using `left_anti` join :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

filter_cond = F.col("StartDate").isNull() & F.col("EndDate").isNull() & F.col("CID").isNull()

df1 = df.alias("df").filter(~filter_cond).join(
    df.filter(filter_cond).select("SID", "Date Added").alias("f"),
    (F.col("df.SID") == F.col("f.SID")) & (F.col("df.`Date Added`") < F.col("f.`Date Added`")),
    "left_anti"
)

df1.show()
#+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
#| SID| StartDate|   EndDate| CID|Date Added|
#+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
#|1005|2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006|2021-03-26|
#|1001|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002|2021-03-29|
#|1001|2021-03-30|2021-03-31|1002|2021-03-29|
#|1004|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003|2021-03-26|
#+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `nulldate` column of the date where the three columns are null, and filter to get the rows where that date does not exist, or `DateAdded` is greater than or equal to that date, and of course, the rows where the three columns are not null.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

cond = F.col('StartDate').isNull() & F.col('EndDate').isNull() & F.col('CID').isNull()

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'nulldate', 
    F.max(
        F.when(
            cond, 
            F.col('DateAdded')
        )
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('SID'))
).filter('(nulldate is null or DateAdded >= nulldate)').filter(~cond).drop('nulldate')

df2.show()
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
| SID| StartDate|   EndDate| CID| DateAdded|
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
|1005|2021-04-06|2021-04-06|1006|2021-03-26|
|1001|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1002|2021-03-29|
|1001|2021-03-30|2021-03-31|1002|2021-03-29|
|1004|2021-04-05|2021-04-05|1003|2021-03-26|
+----+----------+----------+----+----------+
```